# Force change app language without restart

Tags: react-native, redux

Currently my react native app allow language switching by user (have a language selection screen in the app for user to switch) with [`react-native-localization`](https://github.com/stefalda/ReactNativeLocalization). What i did is use redux-persist to store the selected language. But that requires an app restart to take effect.

However, we have a business requirement to switch the language on the fly. Anyone have successfully implement it before?

```
import LocalizedStrings from 'react-native-localization';

export default new LocalizedStrings({
  en: {
  },
  de: {
  },
});
```

In my main navigator:

```
componentDidMount() {
    const language = store.getState().language;
    if (language.code) {
      LocalizedStrings.setLanguage(language.code);
    } else {
      LocalizedStrings.setLanguage('en');
    }
  }
```

Anyone have successfully implemented in such a way that an app restart is not required?

Comment: This is too broad of a question.  Yes it's possible just  tie all text to your template file and switch it based on the language you select

Answer (score 1):

When language got update, you just need to update `key` of the root component to force all child component re-render.
In my case, I am using `react-navigation`, whenever language changed. I update `screenProps`

```
export default () => {
  const language = useSelector((state: AppState) => state.preferences.language);
  return (
    <AppContainer
      screenProps={{ language }}
      ...
    />
  );
};
```